# Powershell: How do add Delimiter to Integer?

Tags: powershell

**Use Case:** I want to add a delimeter to an Integer Result in `Powershell` (without destroying the Integer)

```
[int]$Result = ($foo).Count
Write-Output $Result

$> 2221
```

Desired Result (Examples)

```
$>  2.221
$> 10.429
etc ...
```

Is there any smart way? I would strongly avoid dirty tricks like converting Int to String.

Comment: Considering that the act of outputting it *on the console* requires the integer to be converted to a string, I'm not sure why you're reluctant to do that, but you can use formatting, `Write-Output '{0:N0}' -f $Result`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for pointing me to the Format Option! https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-and-conditional-formatting-to-format-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

```
Write-Output '{0:N0}' -f $Result
```

Has solved my issue. Thank you!